# How to handle refused mail?

Tags: email, newsletter, bulk

I've been asked to set up a newsletter service for ~10k recipients (all signed up, no spam)
The thing is I got a lot of rejected emails (non existing addresses),which flooded my inbox.
I wrote a shell script to parse these mails, extract the addresses, and remove them from my database. Is there a better option? I have access to everything (mail list, mail server, newsletter service source).
If I'm not being clear enough please tell me so I can clarify

Comment: Basically you seem to be doing everything right.  BATV is one option, another is having the return address be a mailbox created specially for collecting the bounces.

Comment: The return address is what I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you seem to be doing everything right. BATV is one option for etending your bounce handling, another is having the return address be a mailbox created specially for collecting the bounces.